# videosjs - As the tooltip effect is applied i captions "cc" icon?

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to code a skin to videojs an and i need apply the same effect of cc (captions) in volume bar that is inside div.vjs-volume-control. How can i copy the tooltip effect to volume bar?

I can do this with jquery by myself but i would like to know if it can be done without jquery.

In video.js line 1446 i have:

```
_V_.MuteToggle = _V_.Button.extend({

    init: function(player, options){
    init: function(player, options){
    this._super(player, options);
    player.addEvent("volumechange", _V_.proxy(this, this.update));    
    });
},
```

i take a look and did that:

```
_V_.MuteToggle = _V_.Button.extend({

    init: function(player, options){  
    this._super(player, options);
    //var volume = _V_('volumeBar');
    player.addEvent("volumechange", _V_.proxy(this, this.update));
    this.addEvent("mouseover",  function(){
     var barra = new _V_.VolumeControl(this.player);
    //alert('sdsd');
    barra.fadeOut();
    });
},
```

the alert works. but when i thy to hide volume bar it not works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Comment: hello! i edited the question with what i tried. thx